# Как правильно выстроить иерархию ссылок?

Tags: html

Сверстала свой первый небольшой сайт-каталог. Сайт имеет множество страниц. Для каждой страницы идет свой файл html, которую помещала корень папки site. Получается, что в одной папке site идут подряд все файлы html. На данный момент, ссылка на определенный товар строится след. образом: site.ru/tovar1.html. Хотя , по факту чтобы найти этот товар, человек выбирает на сайте Каталог, далее Раздел каталога и уже сам товар.

Вопрос такой: верно ли то, что все внутренние страницы имеют один уровень вложенности, например site.ru/tovar1.html., site.ru/tovar2.html., site.ru/contacts.html и.т.д.? Или мне каждую страницу нужно распределить по определенным папкам? Или не имеет значения?

Сайт не на CMS!

Comment: Располагать страницы на 1 уровне неправильно. Нужно организовывать ЧПУ формат. И поисковики будут правильно парсить. Для примера - товары в `site.ru/products/имя-товара`, категории в  `site.ru/categories/имя-категории` и тп. Для статичного сайта можно просто создать соответствующие папки. И поменять соответствующие ссылки.

Answer (score 1):

Создайте папки для каждого раздела и в них положите все подходящие файлы html